# Setting Right-To-Left orientiation for a hebrew text in MS access

Tags: ms-access, right-to-left, hebrew

I've an excel sheet which contains english to hebrew text translastions. Some of these translation contain words of a left-to-right (english words) and right-to-left (hebrew words) languages. 
In excel I can use the RTL ribbon which sets the translation actually to right-to-left.

For example:

> מעצור חירום (אוטומטי) - LZB

which is as expected.

Now I try to import the data from the excel sheet to an MS-Access database. Unfortunaly, MS access mixes up the formatting of the above example translation to

> LZB -  מעצור חירום (אוטומטי)

which is wrong!

I have searched the internet for a possibilty to enable in MS access a right-to-left orientation for my imported translations, but unfortunately there is nothing useful to solve this issue. MS-Access uses "Context related" orientation as described here 
https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Right-to-left-language-features-17D8A34D-36D6-49AD-B765-257CB7CD22E2

in section "About text direction in Access or Excel".

Question: Is there a possibility in MS-Access or VBA/Macro to force a right-to-left orientation for my hebrew text translations?

Thank you so far!

Comment: I'm investigating the same issue. I'm about to build an application which will need to handle both English and Hebrew text, but there is preciously little information on this (at least in english).